# Portforwarding to VM doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, iptables

I have a windows 2k8 server VM on my Ubuntuserver which I use for i.e terraria & apache.

It was working great before a little minor accident when the electricity stopped flowing through the cables which ended up killing the server. When I booted it up again all the portforwarding rules in iptables was gone. Isn't iptables-save suppose to be enough?

Well, I tried to set it up again by forwarding `8888` to `80`. Which didn't work.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.113 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.40:80
```

Tried changing `-d 192.168.0.113` to `-i eth1` which didn't work either.

The VM is online (I can VNC in through Chicken VNC) and has access to interwebs and network. I can even ping it from the host. But why cant I get the host to forward these ports to it?

The host is accepting everything so the port isn't blocked.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.113       tcp dpt:8888 to:192.168.122.40:80 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

Any ideas?